# Constructing a piecewise-defined function in Scilab

Tags: function, scilab

I'm trying to create the function :

- x(t) = -1 if t<0
- x(t) = 1 if t>0

So I did this :

```
function y = x(t);
    if t == 0
        y = 0;
    elseif t < 0
    y = -1;
    else
        y = 1;
    end
endfunction

t = linspace(0,100,1000);
plot(t,x(t));
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work, because if t is a vector (has more than one element), e.g. t=[-1 0 1] then
t==0 yields a vector result: [F T F]. Thus you always got the else solution: y=1. To make it work, you can:

1.) use a for loop and check every element of the t vector individually:

```
function y = x(t);
  for i=1:size(t,"*")
    if t(i) == 0
      y(i) = 0;
    elseif t(i) < 0
      y(i) = -1;
    else
      y(i) = 1;
    end
  end
endfunction

t = linspace(-1,1,10);
clf();
plot2d(t,x(t),rect=[-1,-2,1,2]);
```

2.) use the builtin sign() function, which does exactly the same, and work not only for vectors but also for matrices:

```
t = linspace(-1,1,10);
clf();
plot2d(t,sign(t),rect=[-1,-2,1,2]);
```